# GWT compiler doesn't create symbolMaps in the right place

Tags: gwt, logging, maven

I recently integrated [gwt-log](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-log/) into my [GWT](http://gwt.google.com) and Maven based project mostly because of it's ability to automatically deobfuscate client side stack traces on the server. To make this possible gwt-log needs a so called symbol-map which maps all of the obfuscated symbol names to the original Java symbol names. The GWT compiler is capable of generating these symbol maps but for some reason they are saved to a strange location, eg.:

target/project-name-1.0-SNAPSHOT/project-name/.junit_symbolMaps/0F9FD6EF6A1BC63EA834AC33C7ED13F3.symbolMap

According to the [GWT Maven Plugin Documentation](http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/compile-mojo.html#deploy) the GWT compiler has a "-deploy" parameter which determines where to create files like that and which per default points to "WEB-INF/deploy". But even if I manually set this parameter to the correct location the compiler still creates the symbol-maps in the wrong folder.

I even downloaded the GWT Maven Plugin sources and added some log output to find out whether or not the "-deploy" parameter is passed correctly to the compiler but all seems fine.

Has anybody experienced a similar behavior?

Thanks!
Michael

Comment: Did you know GWT has a built-in logging system (using the java.util.logging API) that deobfuscates stacktraces too? And it uses the files from `WEB-INF/deploy` by default, that's why the compiler outputs them there (by default).  
See http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideLogging.html

Comment: Thanks Thomas Broyer, I didn't know that. Looks very promising but it doesn't really solve my problem because nothing except the serialization policy is generated in `WEB-INF/deploy`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disable JUnit GWT Module.

http://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit/browse_thread/thread/552a9578a76587ae#

Comment: I'm unable to find the file that includes JUnit.gwt.xml... Any ideas?

Comment: Finally I had time to take a look at it again. It turned out the the JUnit.gwt.xml dependency was in gwttime. I removed it and, finally, the symbolMaps are created!